# CDF plot doesn't start from zero

Tags: matlab, plot, cdf

I've tried to plot cdfcurves of my data by calling `cdfplot(x)` function. Here is part of my code:

```
    figure; 
    for i=1:length(num_curves)
        h = cdfplot(10*log10(plot_vec1(:,i)));
        set(h,'Linewidth',2,'Color',cc(i,:),'Linestyle','-');
        hold on
        %set(color, cc(i,:));
    end
```

Unfortunately the result I get is very confusing. 
[image]

Yellow and purple curves are starting from nonzero value, but CDF curve should always start from zero!
Can anyone give me some suggestions? I've tried to plot yellow curve by itself, but it is still 'biased'.
Thank you for help!

Comment: Please post a minimal example with actual values that reproduce the problem

Comment: Do you mean, post vector plot_vec1?

Comment: Yes, but not necessarily your actual data (from the graph it seems to be a large matrix). Just a minimal example with a few values that cause that behaviour

Comment: 0
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
         0
         0
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
         0
         0
         0
         0
         0
    0.0000
    0.0000
         0
         0
         0
    0.0000
         0
    0.0000
         0
    0.0000
         0
         0
    0.0569
    0.0000
         0
         0
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
         0
    0.0000
         0
         0
    0.0000
         0
         0
    0.0000
         0
    0.0500
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0261
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0190
    0.0158
    0.0082

Comment: 0.0121
    0.0023
    0.0094
    0.0018
    0.0061
    0.0067
    0.0037
    0.0110
    0.0165
    0.0137
    0.0046
    0.0007
    0.0203
    0.0159
    0.0149
    0.0059
    0.0044
    0.0105
    0.0122
    0.0086
    0.0057
    0.0104
    0.0034
    0.0048
    0.0055
    0.0030
    0.0043
    0.0118
    0.0285
    0.0025
    0.0245

Comment: these are values of plot_vec1, that on my plot correspond to yellow curve(just a few values)

Comment: Ahh I see, try to take the logarithm of zero :P. The cdf plot neglects -Inf.

Comment: Then, how can smartly fix it? Make log(epsilon + x)

Comment: @MykolaServetnyk that would not work either, the you will have a lot of samples `log(eps)`. The CDF plot does only plot samples and your suggestion leads to an accumulation of samples around `log(eps)`. What you need to do is to think about how you need to think about is how you want to represent the zeroes. Do you want them to be ignored as if no samples existed? Do you want to keep the current graph to show there are more samples with a value below minimum threshold? Or do you want another representation. This is typically application dependent. Please think about this an comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your data `plot_vec1` contains zeros. Those zeros are transformed to `-inf` when you transform to dB with `10*log10()`. Then `cdfplot` sees that the minimum finite value (about `-67` in your yellow curve) has many samples (with value `-inf`) below it. That's why it gives a non-zero accumated probability there.

For example, compare these two figures

1. Normal case, all values are finite:

   ```
   cdfplot([1 2 3 4 5 6])
   ```

   [image]
2. Some values are `-inf`:

   ```
   cdfplot([-inf -inf 3 4 5 6])
   ```

   [image]

   Here the minimum finite value, which is `3`, has a `0.33` cumulative probability shown on the vertical axis. That's because 2 of the 6 samples are `- inf` and are thus below `3`:

Possible workarounds: remove those zeros before applying the logarithm, or replace the resulting `-inf` by a very small value in dB, such as `-100`.